# ZF1 Primary key column(s) are not columns in this table

Tags: php, zend-framework

I get error when i try list users  in Zend Framework 1:

Primary key column(s) (id) are not columns in this table ()"

Controller :

```
public function listAction(){

    $mapper = new Application_Model_UserMapper();
    $users = $mapper->fetchAll();
```

Mapper :

```
public function fetchAll($where=null)
{

    $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($where);

    return $resultSet;
```

dbtable

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $name = 'users';

    protected $_primary ='id';

}
```

Model

```
class Application_Model_User {

    protected $_id;
    protected $_useremail;
    protected $_usergroup;
    protected $_password;
    protected $_password_salt;
```

Sql :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    useremail VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(32) NULL,
    password_salt VARCHAR(32) NULL,
    usergroup VARCHAR(12) NULL,
    real_name VARCHAR(150) NULL
);
CREATE INDEX "idUser" ON "users" ("useremail");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property to set the table name is $_name, not $name.

https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php#L131